# how to access the data sent from server(using flask), in javascript code?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, server

from my server I sent a data like this to my front end,

return render_template("home.html", username=username)

I can access this data in the HTML using {{ username }}

But if I want to use this in javascript code(in script tags) how would I do that?

Comment: Not familiar with how flasks rendering process but I would definitely try to change the delimiter, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the data fetched from a Flask server in script tags, you have to convert the object into JSON representation which you can easily do by using Flask's `tojson()` template filter. For more info about `tojson()` visit this [link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/templating/#standard-filters).

Solution to your problem -

```
<script>
    var username = JSON.parse('{{ username | tojson | safe}}');
    //you can now use it in whichever way you want to
</script>
```

Hope this works for you.